# What is the ubuntu 16.04 lts server default login & password?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-14.04

When i installed dual boot ubuntu 16.04 lts server i did not entry any ubuntu server login & password when i opened ubuntu server it wants  login & password.What     is the ubuntu 16.04 lts server default login & password ?or How to open ubuntu server?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't remember the password, you can reset it with a liveCD/USB, you need to boot the USB, mount your root partition, chroot and reset the password:

```
# mkdir /mnt/ubuntu
# mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/ubutnu # your partition numeber
# chroot /mnt/ubuntu /bin/bash
# passwd [your username] # here you reset the password
# exit
# reboot
```

If You want to know your username put this command in your chroot environment:

```
# grep 1000 /etc/passwd
```

It should be the last one and the UID should be 1000 on a fresh installation
if you have not a UID 1000 means you have not created a username, so add it, always on your chroot environment:

```
# uaseradd -s /bin/bash -G users,wheel,... [your username]
# passwd [your username]
```

Comment: Note: not every liveCD/USB will work: (1) the implicit premise is it contains Linux; (2) `chroot` will use the kernel of this live OS, version mismatch may be an issue in general (although the mentioned commands should not be picky, I guess).

Comment: first... thanks, about the editing... my english is not perfect :P 
second... It is true, Its recommended to use the same liveCD/USB used to install the SO

Comment: Even with use of the actual install media you may have a mismatch, e.g. if there has been updates that included changes to system portions that affects what you're about to handle.

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu, you do not need to boot a live CD (and chroot) as you should be able to use the `... (recovery mode)` option in the grub menus.

To see the grub menu; hold SHIFT as the BIOS ends it's boot-up display.

Select the recovery mode with the cursor keys (then press ENTER) and a new menu appears.

Select and press enter on
`fsck           Check all file systems`
to make all filesystems writable.

Select  and press enter on
`network            Enable networking`
... if also need networking (e.g. to run apt-get)

Select and press enter on
`root           Drop to root shell prompt`
... and ENTER once more, to get the root shell prompt.

Now use `useradd`, `usermod`, `userdel` and `passwd` in the normal way to reset password(s) or create/modify/remove users.

---

*Note also: ALL answers here should be considered "$3cur1ty h0l3z" - anybody with physical access to the machine can do this; root access without effort. So, what to do? -> Keep your computer in a locked room.*